# unknown "ptr" variable in golang asm code

Tags: go

Recently I just begin to read the source code of atomic.LoadUint64, then I got an unknown variable "ptr" in the following asm code:

```
TEXT runtime∕internal∕atomic·Load64(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-12                                                                                                                                                                                       
    MOVL    ptr+0(FP), AX                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    TESTL   $7, AX                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    JZ  2(PC)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    MOVL    0, AX // crash with nil ptr deref                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    MOVQ    (AX), M0                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    MOVQ    M0, ret+4(FP)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    EMMS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    RET
```

I couldn't find the declaration of this variable, and any documents about this variable, can anyone tell me about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [A Quick Guide to Go's Assembler](https://golang.org/doc/asm)
>
> [Symbols](https://golang.org/doc/asm#symbols)
>
> The `FP` pseudo-register is a virtual frame pointer used to refer to
>   function arguments. The compilers maintain a virtual frame pointer and
>   refer to the arguments on the stack as offsets from that
>   pseudo-register. Thus `0(FP)` is the first argument to the function,
>   `8(FP)` is the second (on a 64-bit machine), and so on. However, when
>   referring to a function argument this way, it is necessary to place a
>   name at the beginning, as in `first_arg+0(FP)` and `second_arg+8(FP)`.
>   (The meaning of the offset—offset from the frame pointer—distinct from
>   its use with `SB`, where it is an offset from the symbol.) The
>   assembler enforces this convention, rejecting plain `0(FP)` and
>   `8(FP)`. The actual name is semantically irrelevant but should be used
>   to document the argument's name. It is worth stressing that `FP` is
>   always a pseudo-register, not a hardware register, even on
>   architectures with a hardware frame pointer.

---

`ptr`, in `ptr+0(FP)`, is a name for the first argument to the function. The argument is probably a pointer.

Comment: thank you, that explains everything, and I think I should go through the guide with more detail.